# Javascript conditions in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm pretty new in js, I have an array that looks like this:

```
[ 'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,off',
  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on'
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,off',
  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpksfhksfMmqkPczCl2,off' ]
```

How can I delete the rows from the array that has:
-> the last value "off" AND the first two values the same as a line with the "on" value
 like this:

```
   (*) [ 'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',
      'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
      'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on',
      'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
      'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpksfhksfMmqkPczCl2,off' ]
```

So I was like:

```
var productIds = [];
var userIds = [];
var status = [];
unique.forEach(function(data) {
  var dataArray = data.split(',');
  productIds.push(dataArray[0]);
  userIds.push(dataArray[1]);
  status.push(dataArray[2]);
});

for (var h = 0; userIds.length >= h; h++) {
  if (status[h] == "on") {
    for (var k = 0; userIds.length >= k; k++) {
      if (status[k] == "off" && 
          userIds[h] == userIds[k] && 
          productIds[h] == productIds[k]) {
        delete status[k];
        delete userIds[k];  
        delete productIds[k];
      }
    }    
  }
}
```

But I think it is so much code... and well, just the forEach is the one working fine (separating into three objects) And the for loops I think work wrong because forEach is async. So is there any way I could improve the code to get that output mentioned (*)?

After this I need to send the array with the off rows that were left.

Comment: `userIds.length >= k` ?

Comment: Don't use `delete` for removing elements from an array.

Comment: What can I use instead? for an specific index?

Comment: use `arr.splice(index, count)`. You can find more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array filter.

Here an example:

```
var array = ['com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on', 'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,off', 'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on', 'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on', 'com-fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,off', 'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on'];

function checkFilter(str) {
   return str.indexOf('off') !== str.length - 3 || str.indexOf('co') !== 0;
}

function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  array.filter(checkFilter);
}
```

You can test this code here http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBN71QBHVUS1

The doc http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Comment: This also keeps the "off" rows wich has different productId and userId from the "on" exsting?

Comment: does everybody miss the "AND the first two values the same as a line with the "on" value" part of the question?

Comment: @arnoldssss You have to add the condition in the filter and thats all... I modified the code

Comment: @amaia `str.indexOf('co') !== 0` - what does this mean? `str` passed to `checkFilter` has to be checked against other array items.

Comment: @Igor str is the string of every item, sorry for my bad english.. the function checkFilter is gonna be called for every item of array... the function indexof find in the string the ocurrence of 'co' and returns the position, so, if 'co' is in the beginning, his position be 0.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = ['com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,off',
  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,off',
  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpksfhksfMmqkPczCl2,off'
];

// es6
// var output = data.filter(d => !(d.endsWith('off') && data.find(val => val.endsWith('on') && val.startsWith(d.substr(0, d.length - 3)))));

// es5
var output = data.filter(function(d) {
  return !(d.indexOf('off') === d.length - 3 && data.filter(function(val) {
    return val.indexOf('on') === val.length - 2 && val.indexOf(d.substr(0, d.length - 3)) === 0
  }).length);
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: should be noted: this es6 version is concise, also won't work in IE before Edge or Opera as of right now.

Comment: thanks for reminding that IE still exists, updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If your array is not too long (if the efficiency is not so critical) then you can hack the `.sort()` function of the `Array` and get your desired output.

```js
var arr = [ 'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,off',
  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,off',
  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpksfhksfMmqkPczCl2,off' ];

var removeOffOrOnFromStr = function(str){
  return str.split(",", 2).toString()
}

var removeOffFromArray = function(arr, first, second){
  var off = first;
  if(second[second.length - 1] == "f"){
    off = second;
  }
  arr.splice(arr.indexOf(off), 1)
}

var filtered = arr.slice()

arr.sort(function(first, second){
  var removedOnOrOff1 = removeOffOrOnFromStr(first)
  var removedOnOrOff2 = removeOffOrOnFromStr(second)
  var thirdValueDiff = false
  if(first[first.length - 1] != second[second.length - 1]){
    thirdValueDiff = true
  }
  
  if(removedOnOrOff1 == removedOnOrOff2 && thirdValueDiff ){
    removeOffFromArray(filtered, first, second)
  }
});

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use Array.filter() method.

Please find details here

[MDN Array filter method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: While `.filter` will likely solve the issue, your answer is more useful if you show how it works. Right now it's basically just a link only answer, which is considered low quality.

Comment: Ok I'll try to make an implementation with filter, but if I need to delete a specific index with on value, how can I delete this in the logic of the "map"?

Answer (score -1):

*edit*: I did miss your second requirement, now fixed, still using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) plus a (very) small bit of regex:

```
var target = [ 'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,on',  'com--test,LFutx9mQbTTyRo4A9Re5ksjdnfsI4cKN4q2,off',  'com--fxtrimester,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,on',  'com--fxtrimester,LFutx9mQbTTyRoldksfns4A9Re5I4cKN4q2,off',  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpW3FxkSbzL7eo5MmqkPczCl2,on',
  'com--fxyear,SEzlksdfMpksfhksfMmqkPczCl2,off' ];
var withOn = target.filter(function(el){return /on$/.test(el)});
var filteredResult = target.filter(
    function(el){  
        var valueToMatch= el.match(/.*(?=,)/);//everything up to last comma
        return !(/off$/.test(el) && withOn.filter(function(el){ return el.match(valueToMatch);}).length>0);//check for ending with 'off' and that one of the 'ons' has the same value
});
console.log(filteredResult);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, don't just dump code. An explanation is much useful for other visitors.

Comment: This just remove the rows with off... I need those off only be removed if the first two parameters are equal to a "on" row

Comment: does everybody miss the "AND the first two values the same as a line with the "on" value" part of the question?

Comment: apparently yes, heh. I've fixed my answer, fwiw.